# How to wait for actual data from resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

So I have an angular app using ui-router. I have a resolve using the resource to get data.

app.config.js

```
resolve: {
                data: function ($resource) {

                    var dataObj= $resource('/api/area/162');

                    return dataObj.get({},function(result){
                        return result;
                    });
                }
            }
```

my controller inside called component

```
...

                var $ctrl = this;
                    console.log("data", $ctrl);
...
```

Now I know that angular assigns empty value to return an object while waiting for data. which in return results in the execution of component and I end up with empty data in the component controller. Now how to force angular to wait for the data from server, before executing controller

when I try

```
            resolve: {
                data: function ( $http) {

                    return $http.get('/api/area/162').then(function(response) {
                       return  response.data;
                    });

                }
            }
```

everything is working fine, the view isn't loaded before the data is fetched and I can see the data in my controller. How can I  achieve the same result using the resource ?

I have also tried:

app.config.js

```
            resolve: {
                data: function (Data, $stateParams, $http, $resource) {

                    var object = $resource('/api/area/162');

                    return object.get().$promise.then(function(result){
                        return result;
                    });
               }
            }
```

this just returns an error:

```
stateService.ts:526 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at data (app.config.js:81)
at resolvable.ts:120
at angular.js:17051
at m.$digest (angular.js:18233)
at angular.js:18462
at e (angular.js:6362)
at angular.js:6642
```

I have read most of the questions on StackOverflow regarding similar problems as well as some articles including

https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/

Comment: By adding a $watch on data inside controller I'm able to do stuff when the data arrives, however I think that's just wrong and it shouldn't be done like that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had the wrong version of angular-resource.js :/

So, this actually works ....

app.config.js

```
        resolve: {
            data: function (Data, $stateParams, $http, $resource) {

                var object = $resource('/api/area/162');

                return object.get().$promise.then(function(result){
                    return result;
                });
           }
        }
```

Problem solved :P